# Смена иконки (реализация)

Tags: javascript

Ниже код, в котором должна иконка `microphone` меняться на `microphone-slash` и наоборот в зависимости от режима отображения ***(воспроизведение или пауза)***.

Но этого не происходит. Не могу понять, в чём дело!

```js
let play = document.querySelector('.play');
// создаем объект AUDIO 
const audio = new Audio();

// сразу выставляем уровень звука на 20% 
let volume = .2
audio.volume = volume;

// присваиваем объекту AUDIO трек 
audio.src = 'ytytytytytyt.ru:8040/…';

// показываем какой уровень выставлен 
document.querySelector('.vol').innerHTML = audio.volume * 10;

// функция для понижения уровня звука 
document.querySelector('.volume-down').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.volume !== 0) {
    volume -= .1;
    // метод .toFixed() нужен для того чтобы убрать 
    // все лшние цифры кроме первой после точки 
    audio.volume = volume.toFixed(1);
    document.querySelector('.vol').innerHTML = audio.volume * 10;
    audio.muted = false;
  }
});
document.querySelector('.volume-up').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.volume !== 1) {
    volume += .1;
    audio.volume = volume.toFixed(1);
    document.querySelector('.vol').innerHTML = audio.volume * 10;
    audio.muted = false;
  }
});

// функция для полного отключения звука 
document.querySelector('.mute').addEventListener('click', () => {
  audio.muted = audio.muted == false ? true : false;
})


// функция для запуска и паузы музыки 
play.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    play.classList.add('fa fa-microphone slash');
    play.classList.remove('fa fa-microphone');
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    play.classList.remove('fa fa-microphone-slash');
    play.classList.add('fa fa-microphone');
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!--кнопка запуска плеера она же и пауза-->
<button class="play fa fa-microphone"></button>
<!--кнопка понижения звук-->
<button class="volume-down">-</button>
<!--кнопка повышение звука-->
<button class="volume-up">+</button>
<!--уровень звука-->
<span class="vol"></span>
<!--кнопка отключения звука-->
<button class="mute">Mute</button>
```

Comment: пропущен дефис `play.classList.add('fa fa-microphone slash');`

Comment: @Igor да, был пропущен. Исправил. Результат отсутствует, как и раньше.

Answer (score 3):

Убери `fa`

```
play.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    play.classList.add('fa-microphone-slash');
    play.classList.remove('fa-microphone');
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    play.classList.remove('fa-microphone-slash');
    play.classList.add('fa-microphone');
  }
})
```

Пример наглядный... Что бы удалять и добавлять методом `classList.add(` 
надо писать `class-Ы` через запятую каждый класс отдельным аргументом.

А у тебя  `play.classList.remove('fa fa-microphone');`

```js
let play = document.querySelector('.play')
let flag = true;
play.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (flag === true) {
    play.classList.remove('fa', 'pa');
    play.classList.add('zz', 'rr');
    flag = false;
    console.log(play);
  } else {
    play.classList.add('fa', 'pa');
    play.classList.remove('zz', 'rr');
    flag = true;
    console.log(play);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="play fa pa">play</div>
```